# Shoelace formula in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, geometry, polygon, shoelace

Quite new in SQL world here.

I have a database with coordinates to different places (x,y)

Have followed [This guide](https://www.sisense.com/blog/polygon-area-from-latitude-and-longitude-using-sql/) to convert those coordinates to cartesian coordinates and create a list of ordered coordinates which form a polygon.

With that done, I now face the challenge of calculating the area of said polygon.

To achieve that, the best option seems to be an implementation of the [Shoelace Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).
I have found different ways to run the calculation in different languages [(see here)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/area-of-a-polygon-with-given-n-ordered-vertices/)
and [here - page 28, area2d_polygon() function](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzacedttz63pdyfvc4mvpor4kfc4riac4lw5aagbgvh3bfzx3mgddhb3s?filename=Daniel%20Sunday%20PhD%20-%20Practical%20Geometry%20Algorithms.%20%282021%29.pdf), but have not been successful at all in writing the SQL to perform the same calculation.

PostGIS does not seem to be an option for me here.

Have spent quite a few hours on this one by now. I need to write the SQL that calculates an area in km2 from a list of coordinates that form the polygon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What's wrong with [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_Area.html)?

Comment: *"PostGIS does not seem to be an option for me here."* in that case I believe there is no pleasing you :-D PostGIS is a pretty solid extension for spatial data and imho the best one out there. Good luck! :)